# Logitech G305 wireless mouse is randomly lagging on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: mouse, 20.10

So, I seem to be having the same issues as other people have, but I cannot seem to fix the issue. I am dual booting on my machine, so I know for a fact that my mouse works as it never stutters in Windows. As I mentioned in the title, my mouse lags at random times on a newly installed system. If I use my old mouse that is not wireless it never lags.

Does anyone have any suggestions that I can test?

Update:

The model of the mouse is a Logitech G305. The lagging occurs randomly in the sense that it can work fine for 10-15 minutes and then starts to lag for maybe 1 minute before it starts to work fine again.

I don't have WiFi on the PC.
What I have tried and did not work:

- Restarting Bluetooth
- Removing and reinserting Bluetooth stick that came with the mouse

Comment: Update your original question with some more details, you have not even said what make/model of mouse it is, how often the lagging occurs etc. My only suggestion would be to turn off Bluetooth and/or Wi-Fi on your PC to see if any interference is causing the issues.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the original question as you suggested! :)